# Set baud rate to pts

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Now I can send and receive messages from two different pts's in the same computer(they both set to 9600 baud rate),

I want to check what will happen if i change in one of the pts the baud rate, so in this way the 2 pts's will have different baud rates.
And in this way I hope that when I will send message from one to another, nothing will happened.

Lets say I have `/dev/pts/1` and `/dev/pts/2`
I have tried this command in the one of the terminal: `stty -F /dev/pts/1 4800`, and after use this command I verified that the baud rate is change by the command line: `stty -F /dev/pts/1`   and saw that the baud rate has changed from `9600` to `4800`, and after this I have tried to send messages between the two, and the messages still receive, which I thought it will not receive.

In the first terminal I write in the command line `echo "Test" > /dev/pts/1`     and in the second terminal I wrote `cat < /dev/pts/2`     in the command line and saw at the console "Test".

I'm using Ubuntu .

Comment: Changing the baud rate has no on the data transfer across pseudo terminals, as you have discovered.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is do nothing.